# upload image using objective-c 

Tags: iphone, ajax, ios, cocoa-touch, nsconnection

I'm writing an iPhone app for a web service and I need to upload image to the service. In the web version, it's using AJAX. But I know little about that. I find the following code on the web page for the upload button:

```
        if (button.length) {
        new AjaxUpload(button, {
            action: '/Media/UploadFile',
            responseType: 'json',
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                $('#bBar').progressBar(0);
                var uid = createUUID();
                timerID = setTimeout(function () { checkImageUploadProgress(uid, 1, 'image') }, 1000);
                startUpload();
                this.setData({ fileType: 1, guid: uid, DJUploadStatus: '::DJ_UPLOAD_ID::' + uid });
            },
            onComplete: function (file, response) {
            }
        });
    }
```

How should I implement this function using the NSConnection class?

Comment: Try searching for it! There are plenty of codes for that on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTP vs HTTP upload on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1784930/840973)

[upload image from iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481859/840973)

[Upload image along with other data in same POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065990/840973)

[iPhone UIImage upload to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901797/840973)

And there's plenty more.
I'm sure you'll manage to do it the answers to these questions.